# If formula with comma output

Tags: excel

How can I make this if formula work?

```
=IF(J1="b","b","$A1,$B1")
```

Here if the first condition is false, then the output should be `"$A1,$B1"`.
but I get literally `$A1,$B1` in this case. Instead, I want the values of `A1` and `B1` to be output comma separated. E.g: (1,2) How can I fix this, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of these,

```
=IF(J1="b", "b", $A1&","&$B1)
=IF(J1="b", "b", concatenate($A1, ",", $B1))
=IF(J1="b", "b", TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, $A1:$B1))
```

CONCATENATE has been 'grandfathered' out in favor of CONCAT with newer versions but if you have CONCAT then you should have TEXTJOIN which is the better choice.

Comment: Aww crap I left out `TEXTJOIN` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&` or if you prefer `CONCATENATE`.

`=IF(J1="b","b",A1&","&B1)` or `=IF(J1="b","b",CONCATENATE(A1,",",B1))`